# Custom authentication scheme with AbpMvcAuthorize

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm having trouble making `AbpMvcAuthorize` attribute working in my special case.

I have some custom authentication mechanism (with a custom `AuthenticationScheme`), that sign-in my user.
To do that, I implemented a `AuthenticationHandler<MyCustomAuthenticationOptions>` and overrode the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method and registered it inside the `AuthConfigurer.Configure` method from the Module-zero :

```
services.AddAuthentication(o => o.AddScheme("amx", b => b.HandlerType = typeof (MyCustomAuthenticationHandler)));
```

Now if I have this:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "amx")]
public string GetTest()
{
    return "OK";
}
```

And make a request with my special amx header, it's working and I can only access the method when I'm specifying it.

If I'm doing the same thing with:

```
[AbpMvcAuthorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "amx")]
public string GetTest()
{
    return "OK";
}
```

It's not working anymore and I have a 401 Unauthorized result and in debug mode, I never enter my custom `AuthenticationHandler`.
It seems like either the `AbpMvcAuthorize` attribute was executed BEFORE my custom `AuthenticationHandler` or maybe it didn't read the `AuthenticationScheme` property?

Have any idea if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.Web.Mvc/Web/Mvc/Authorization/AbpMvcAuthorizeAttribute.cs#L29

Comment: I'm using asp.net core, this is not the same https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Mvc/Authorization/AbpMvcAuthorizeAttribute.cs

Answer (score 0):

I asked on their Github: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3778

And was told that this is not possible right now because the `AbpMvcAuthorize` doesn't read the `AuthenticationScheme` property.
I'll try to implement it with some Policy